# Auto scroll to top dropdown when selected option with multi select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi-select like the attachment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuBRq.png)
When I select any option at the bottom of select, it auto-scrolls to the top
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rifE0.png)
My HTML

```js
$(function () {
    $(window).mousedown(function() {
        //Hide the menus if visible
        $('select.select').removeClass('visible');
    });

    $('.select-dropdown label').on('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        let select = $('select.select');
        if(select.hasClass('visible')) {
           select.removeClass('visible');
        } else {
           select.addClass('visible');
        }
    });

    // START: Multiselect without ctrl
    $('select.select option').on('mousedown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var langs = [];
        if ($(this).parent('select')[0].hasAttribute('multiple')) {
            // toggle selection
            if ($(this)[0].hasAttribute('selected')) {
                $(this)[0].removeAttribute('selected');
            } else {
                $(this)[0].setAttribute('selected', '');
            }

            // Set label value
            var selected = $(this).parent('select').find('option:selected', this);
            selected.each(function() {
                langs.push($(this).data('language_name'));
            });
            $(this).parent().siblings('label.label-title').html(langs.join(", ") || "-- Select languages --");
        }
        if ($(this).parents('.select-dropdown').hasClass('select-required')) {
            if (langs.length < 1) {
                $(this).parents('.select-dropdown').find('.alert-error', this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).parents('.select-dropdown').find('.alert-error', this).hide();
            }
        }
    });
    // END: Multiselect without ctrl
});
```

```css
.select-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-grid;
}

.select-dropdown label,
.select-dropdown select.select{
    width: 350px;
}

.ps15 .select-dropdown label {
    height: auto;
    width: 314px;
}

.select-dropdown label {
    height: 39px;
    padding: 10px 25px 10px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bbcdd2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-align: left;
}

#tabList .select-dropdown label{
    font-weight: normal !important;
}

.select-dropdown label:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-color: #bbcdd2 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.select-dropdown select.select {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    display: none!important;
}

.select-dropdown select.select.visible {
    display: inline-block!important;
    z-index: 2;
}

.ps17 .select-dropdown select.select.visible {
    width: 98%;
}

.select-dropdown select.select option {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 1px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.select-dropdown select.select option:disabled {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.select-dropdown select.select option:checked,
.select-dropdown select.select option:hover {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.select-dropdown select.select option:checked:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: "\2713";
    top: 7px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    color: green;
}
.ps17 .select-dropdown select.select option:checked::after {
    top: 8px;
}

.select-dropdown .alert-error {
    width: max-content;
}
/* END: Multi select */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-dropdown select-required">
                                        <label class="label-title">English (English)</label>
                                        <select class="select" name="multi_languages[]" multiple="">
                                                                                            <option value="en" data-language_name="English (English)" selected="">
                                                    English (English)
                                                </option>
                                                                                            <option value="fr" data-language_name="Français (French)">
                                                    Français (French)
                                                </option>
                                                                                            <option value="gb" data-language_name="English GB (English)">
                                                    English GB (English)
                                                </option>
                                                                                            <option value="es" data-language_name="Español (Spanish)">
                                                    Español (Spanish)
                                                </option>
                                                                                            <option value="it" data-language_name="Italiano (Italian)">
                                                    Italiano (Italian)
                                                </option>
                                                                                    </select>
                                        <span class="alert-error" style="display: none; color: #8b0000; position: absolute; left: 380px; top: 12px;">This field requires at least one value</span>
                                    </div>
```

You can check out my demo to see what happens.
How do I select the option but not scroll to the top?
Hoping can find some help. Thank you!

Comment: What library are you using to create this custom select field? You should provide a proper [mre] when asking this kind of question, not just snippets that lack context.

Comment: Hi @CBroe I just use simple Jquery and don't use any other library

Comment: But that doesn't look much like a native `select` element to me ...? Either way, please provide the MRE you were asked for.

Comment: Hi @CBroe. You can see my code demo to know what happen. Thanks

Comment: Looks to me like the actual toggling of the option's `selected` state is what makes it scroll up. Not sure if there is anything that can be done about that, with a native `select` field.